# Which probability result is greater? Using hypergeometric distribution or binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, binomial-distribution, hypergeometric-distribution

Suppose I have $N$ samples, and 1/4 of them are bad. I draw $n$ samples $(n<N)$, and I want to know what's the probability that less than 1/3 are bad. I know it should use hypergeometric distribution to calculate, that is:

[using hypergeometric distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnmAq.png)

And I understand that if N approaches to infinity, then we can use binomial distribution to calculate the value, that is:

[using binomial distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGJx0.png)

My question is: when $N$ is not infinity, then which probability is greater? Using hypergeometric distribution or binomial distribution? Is there any result in math?

Answer (score 1):

The only simple relationship is that the hypergeometric is **less variable** than the binomial (because it comes from sampling without replacement rather than with replacement). The mean is the same and the variance is smaller by a factor $(N-n)/(N-1)$

So, in your example, the hypergeometric gives you more chance of getting a answer near $n/4$, and less chance of getting an answer far from $n/4$.  The question now is whether $n/3$ is 'near' or 'far from' $n/4$ in this sense.  For large enough $n$ and $N$, $n/4$ will be far from $n/3$, so the probability of getting more than $n/3$ bad out of $n$ will be smaller with the hypergeometric than the binomial.

I don't see any easy way to decide how large $n$ has to be, apart from direct calculation or simulation.